# Apache drill selecting empty arrays from JSON

Tags: hadoop, apache-drill

I am using Apache drill to store large JSON files which I'm then querying using the Drill API as follows:

```
{
    "queryType": "SQL",
    "query": "select * from db.table.`/path/to/JSON.json` w "
}
```

This correctly returns the data. However, some of the JSON files have an empty array.

For example, the following is the JSON stored in the database

```
{
  "key1": ["array", "of", "data"],
  "key2": ["array", "of", "data"],
  "key3": ["array", "of", "data"],
  "key4": ["array", "of", "data"],
  "key5": ["array", "of", "data"],
  "key6": ["array", "of", "data"],
  "key7": [],
}
```

When I retrieve this data, it returns as the following

```
{
  "columns": [
    "key1",
    "key2",
    "key3",
    "key4",
    "key5",
    "key6",
  ],
  "rows": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

`key7` is missing. How do I get the response to show this key even though it maybe empty for some of the stored JSON files.

Answer (score 0):

Drill is schema less, So if there is no data in any row it will ignore that column, if you know that column required, you may need to use "case" or "if" statement to add default value or create a view.